# Limited display connection on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, displayport, usb-c

I have an LG 27UK850-W monitor, which comes with a DisplayPort, a HDMI, and a USB-C cable. The USB-C cable is documented as being for both display as well as for data transfer (the monitor also has a USB socket for quick dongle access) I've connected the DisplayPort and USB-C cables to my computer, but now Windows keeps giving me an error, saying that Display connection might be limited (linking me to [this site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4012609/windows-10-fix-usb-c-problems#connectionlimited)). The monitor otherwise functions fine and the USB port on it also works.

If I disconnect the USB-C cable, the errors go away and the display still works (since it's connected via DisplayPort), but the USB port on the monitor also stops working, so I'd prefer to leave the USB-C cable connected.

So how do I tell Windows that I only want to use the USB-C connection for data transfer, not for display?

Comment: Could be useful knowing your computer specs

Comment: You should use an USB-C port on your computer that has no display feature (usually only one or two very specific USB-C ports have this feature). Or you can get an USB-A to USB-C cable and connect the monitor using this cable. As it lacks the USB-C display feature your computer will no longer be confused.

Comment: Sadly, my computer only has 1 USB-C port that I can see. I'll try to dig up a USB-A <-> USB-C cable or adapter though and see if that helps.

Comment: So I tried to connect it with a USB-A <-> USB-C cable but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Having similar issue; Samsung LS27H850Q monitor, KB & mouse connected to the monitor (USB-A), and USB-C -> USB-A cable from monitor to PC (Windows 10). Using HDMI for display connection. Yet, Windows complains about limited DP connection. Occasionally the machine will not resume from sleep (just showing desktop color), and now I started pondering whether the issue is that Windows is trying to erroneously use this non-existing DP connection as main display, and the HDMI one as 2nd display.

Comment: Related question with no answer on LG community forums: https://lgcommunity.us.com/discussion/15128/display-connection-might-be-limited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workaround that helped me.

I have 2 HP Z42n G2 displays connected via DisplayPort and also USB-C to a Windows 10 machine, so I can use them as displays and USB hubs simultaneously.

The workaround was disabling USB-specific notifications via Start -> Settings -> Devices -> USB and uncheck "Notify me if there are issues connecting to USB devices". Now it doesn't complain anymore, monitors go to sleep as expected, USB devices remain connected, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: It is insane that we have to disable the notification completely for all future devices we might connect in order to stop the messages for a single device.  All the great engineering that went into USB-C and the overall user experience is confused and ruined in this part of Microsoft Windows UI implementation.  Very much like the forever bug where Windows still can't tell you what is preventing "safely eject media"